# How to set the debug and trace function of sql query in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

How to enable debug function for sql query in Apache IoTDB? When I was checking the log of the system, I saw `sql_debug` and `sql_trace` record in the log, but I can’t find how to set these fields in IoTDB. Anyone know how to enable this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the corresponding log level in Apache IoTDB, which is `$IOTDB_HOME/conf/logback-datanode.xml`, and then `sql_debug` and `sql_trace` can be used.